# Creating a python library in C or C++

Tags: c++, python, c

Can C or C++ be used to program a library in python? I know that python can be used to write a library but I am wondering if C or C++ can be used.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/ or http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/ More info there than you can ever bargain for.

Comment: To get started: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/whirlext.html

Comment: ...or you can use the [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) module to call existing C libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely.  There are lots of high performance libraries written in C (simplejson being a notable and fairly simple example.)

See http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages